# angular-fullstack --- where to create my partials?

Tags: angularjs, angular-fullstack

Hi I am trying out the angular-fullstack generator.

I am planning on using 4 state for new, edit, view, all on object called posts which is having title, message, author.

I am wondering how to make partials and all for each to inject into the main.html that I am having.  Where would I put it?

Please let me know thanks.

Comment: instead of asking how to accomplish a list of tasks, it is much better to ask about how to solve issues with your written code. This question is much too broad, seeming more like a request for a tutorial on how to use a library than a specific piece of broken code.

Comment: what does `how to make partials` even mean? Sounds like you should study some tutorials

Comment: ok sorry for the confusion.  I already have created my partial files from previous project.  I am using angular-fullstack now.  I am wondering if best practice is to store my partials in self-created folder `app/partials/edit-post.html` or is there some other directory that should be used for storing my partial files.  Right now, I am having them in the `app/partial` folder, and everything is working fine.  I just wanting to know is this the best place to keep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to create your partials using directive's templateUrl property.